# Where can I legally watch the dubbed version of "Kimi no na wa" ("Your Name")?

Tags: your-name

Is there a dubbed version of *kimi no na wa*, and is there a site to watch the dubbed version of *kimi no na wa* online legally?

Comment: To be clear, what language are you looking for?

Comment: Take note that we don't encourage piracy here, so don't expect to be able to watch it freely, unless there's a legal site that provides it.

Answer (score 4):

According to *Amazon*,  *Your Name* will be releasing **on Blu-Ray & DVD in America on [November 7, 2017](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B074R4KSTM).**

You can pre-order the [DVD + Blu-ray combo pack](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B074R4KSTM) for $20.

[image: Amazon Listing]

Answer (score 3):

If you're in Japan, you will be able to purchase the Blu-Ray [on July 26, 2017](http://www.crunchyroll.com/anime-news/2017/05/10/your-name-japanese-dvdblu-ray-release-date-set-for-july-26-2017).

Amazon seems to be cross-listing this product in their catalog:

- In NA, the release date appears to be [**August 4th**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B07258V1DG).
- In the UK, the release date appears to be [**October 30th**](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Your-Name-Collectors-Blu-ray-DVD/dp/B01MXXEEIM/ref=tmm_blu_title_1?_encoding=UTF8&qid=&sr=).

Depending on where you live, you'll be able to make the purchases when they're available from reputable vendors, like Amazon.  Other specialty shops may sell them slightly earlier.